Concurrency thread not responding back
I'm trying to execute the below code for concurrency but the concurrency threads are never responding back. Please find the below pseudo-code, after creating the 10 parallel threads and the control is going till studentRepo.findStudentsWithPagination method but never responding back and further next code of sending records to kafka is not getting executed, is there any ExecutorService configuration mistake present? or how to debug this scenario, I'm facing this issue in my production environment.
@Component
public class Test{
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo studRepo;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++){
            final int a=i;
                
            executor.submit(()->{
                List<StudentEntity> students = studRepo.findStudentsWithPagination(PageRequest.of(pageNo, 500000));
                log.info("result: {}",students );
                // do some computing here and send to kafka
                kafkaProducer.send(students);
            })
        }
    }
}


"pseudo code" won't be of great help here, can you provide a [mre] too? So is your actual problem that studRepo.findStudentsWithPagination never returns inside the runnable? Where does pageNo come from? Did you implement findStudentsWithPagination yourself?

I would guess the threads have not been created yet when the method is left, the executor service goes out of scope and gets garbage collected, invoking it's shutdown method that will prevent the code getting executed. Try a global executor, or maybe use CompletableFuture.submit().

Properly handle your executor service
As commented, your init method likely exits before the tasks have been executed by the executor service.
And you neglected to shut down your executor service. That means its backing pool of threads may be running indefinitely, possibly even after your app ends, like zombies ‍♂️.
To fix, either:

Use the boilerplate given to you in the Javadoc for ExecutorService. Or…
Use try-with-resources syntax to automatically call close on your choice of implementation of ExecutorService. (The default implementation of close is basically that boilerplate.)

By the way, I would not name the var executor. That name could be misconstrued for the super-interface Executor that has a limited subset of functionality.
By the way, I don’t see the point of your final int a=i; line.
public void init()
{
    try
    (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    )
    {
        for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            executorService.submit
            ( () ->
                {
                    …
                }
            )
        }
        // Flow-of-control blocks here until all the submitted tasks are completed or cancelled. Then the resource is automatically closed.
    }
}

By the way, 10 threads may be a bit too much for a machine with limited number of CPU cores. Either soft-code the number of threads, or use virtual threads.
Virtual Threads
If your tasks are:

not CPU-bound,
not heavily synchronized, and
not making long-running calls to native code

… then consider using virtual threads. If so, change the ExecutorService executorService = line to:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;


If you had posted an MCVE, this Answer would have been more specific.
